# Getting React to only load a component after an action has dispatched and completed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

I have a component 'DashboardServiceEntry' that is used as an entry point to Dashboard.

'Dashboard' reads from Redux the current Options.viewLevel and uses this to make an API call and to show what to display.

Dispatching the action in useEffect in 'DashboardServiceEntry', updates the redux Store, but before this is available in the store The 'Dashboard' component is rendered and reads the wrong value in the redux store, triggering an unnecessary api call.

When the redux Store is updated correctly, another API call (the correct one is started).

How can I make it that the Dashboard component is loaded only after the store has been updated?

Thank you kind people.

```
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import { updateDashOptions } from '../../actions';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

export default function DashboardServiceEntry() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      updateDashOptions({
        viewLevel: 1,
        viewLevel1Title: `Service List`,
      })
    );
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <Dashboard></Dashboard>;
}

    
function Dashboard() {
  let options = useSelector((state) => state.options);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = () => {
      if (options.viewLevel === 0) {
        let uri = createURI(options, options.view);
        dispatch(fetchData(uri, 'SERVICES_SL', dispatch));
      }
      if (options.viewLevel === 1) {
        let uri = createURI(options, 'service');
        dispatch(fetchData(uri, 'SERVICES_SLSSD', dispatch));
      }
    };
    loadData();
  }, [dispatch, options]);
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid unnecessary api call, you can dispatch another action like `isLoading:true` and update it to `false` when you update the correct value of the options and only when its `false`, render the Dashboard component.

Comment: Perfect that was the push I needed. Before this I was trying to render the dashboard based on (options.viewlevel === 1) , but this was not working as the view was able to be changed within dashboard, which would unmount the dash.  Having a separate loading flag - within useState - looks to do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to hear that, please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your question.